# How to authorize clients in non-default directory to KeyVault

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I created a KeyVault in my Azure subscription and a client application in one of my Azure AD directories. However, the client application is not registered in the **default directory** of the subscription.

When I run the following PowerShell cmdlet, it tries to look up the service principal in the default directory of the subscription and fails to find it.

```
PS > Set-AzureKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName <vaultname> 
       -ServicePrincipalName <principal guid> -PermissionsToSecrets Get
```

I found [an article](http://rickrainey.com/windows-azure-how-tos/how-to-change-the-directory-associated-with-your-windows-azure-subscription/) describing how to change the default directory for a subscription in the management portal, but was wondering how to do the same using PowerShell.

The '[`Select-AzureSubscription`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495203.aspx)' cmdlet does not seem to support changing the default directory.
Nor does the '[`Set-AzureKeyVaultAccessPolicy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903607.aspx)' support a parameter to indicate in which directory it should look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key Vault can only authorize applications (clients) registered in the directory associated with the Azure subscription, and the only way (currently) to change the 'home' directory associated with a subscription is through the Azure management portal.

Comment: This is quite limiting, especially in development scenarios where it's not uncommon to have multiple directories. Do you know if there are plans to fix this?

Comment: @MvdD I don't know of any plans that have been shared broadly. Best way to get feedback to team is with the Azure Feedback forums. There's an item already for this, so just pile on the votes: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10510773-allow-key-vault-creation-in-non-default-directory

Comment: Interestingly if you setup access in the default directory successfully and then change the default directory encryption and decryption with the same clientID and secret continues to work from my testing. So it is just the step to grant access that must occur against the default directory apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is as designed behaviour, and can't imagine how / why it would change.

An Azure subscription has an Azure Active Directory attached to it, this is the directory it will use to authenticate against whenever someone tries to access resources.

While you can create trusts to other Active Directories simply creating an new AAD does not automatically enable that domain to be trusted by Azure.

Key Vault is designed to only be accessible to authenticated users, it is designed to provide secure data to those users. Since there is no authentication mechanism between the multiple directories you have created, there is no mechanism for Key Vault to determine who those directories belong to.

Key Vault needs to resolve a service principle through the Active Directory attached to the subscription it is running under (whether that is directly through that directory, or through another domain that it trusts). Anything else would create additional attack vectors and considerably weaken the product.

Comment: While I understand your point (and it is valid), there are plenty of situations (think large companies with enterprise agreements) that will have a valid business case for provisioning subscriptions to internal entities that need separate access to Key Vault for their LOB apps.  Requiring a single directory to house potentially hundreds of LOB applications creates a management and maintenance nightmare for the EA team.  Surely Microsoft can come up with a secure mechanism for allowing applications from an "associated" AAD to authenticate against Key Vault.